# C# Skype Bot Multi Threading

Tags: c#, multithreading, skype, skype4com

So, I have a successful Skype bot that has about 800+ users and growing daily, I am trying to remake the bot for the current one is made very poorly and is quite generic. I'm trying to add a lot of things to it as in databases and multi threading. I have looked at some multi threading threads on here already to try to resolve my problem and I have one that works, i just get a COM exception every time i try to enter the thread itself. IF anyone could help that would be great. I'm new to C# and am learning as I'm going...

Code:

```
private void OnMessage(ChatMessage msg, TChatMessageStatus status)
    {
        if (msg.Body.StartsWith("!") && status == TChatMessageStatus.cmsReceived)
        {
            string message = msg.Body.Replace("!", "");
            string[] cmd = message.Split(' ');
            switch(cmd[0].ToLower())
            {
                case "help":
                    Thread chelp = new Thread(cHelp);
                    chelp.Start();
                    break;
                default:
                    msg.Chat.SendMessage("Command not recognized! Check your usage or type \"!help\" for commands!");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

So this works fine, and it enters the case perfectly, then enters the thread to process the command.

```
private void cHelp()
    {
        msg.Chat.SendMessage("/me Here is a list of commands made by my Master!" +
                "\n\"!help\" - Shows list of commands");
    }
```

So, Once this is entered it breaks and highlights my whole command, saying "COMException was unhandled" 
"Additional Information: Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component"

Screenshot:
[image: Screenshot]

As I said, I'm new to coding so any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Talking to a single COM object from multiple threads isn't inherently safe, are you sure the skype4com component is multi-threaded safe?

Comment: Wow, you really have all those lines hardcoded in a single string?

Comment: Pretty sure you design is wrong... Why did you call a thread to send a message? and msg maybe just be a singleton and you are threading it out. If the class of msg contains the class ChatMessage then you need to initialize a new msg per message... if not you may be able to call a static method

Comment: Likely you are running into an apartment model issue, which is the most common mistake inexperience programmers make when trying to mix COM with threads. But without [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces the problem, it's impossible to say for sure. Try making sure you only ever use the COM object in the thread where it was created.

Comment: @YaWang I tried that, It threw another exception for the method being called.

Comment: @RonBeyer Yes, I have friends with bots who have every case statement run through separate threads.